# React components on path="/" are not rendered when using react-router-dom Router

Tags: reactjs

I KNOW QUESTION WITH THIS ERROR HAS BEEN ASKED BEFORE BUT NOTHING I SAW WORKES FOR ME .On my react website i am trying to make routing to the pages for better rendering , without reloading of the page. But for some reason i keep getting error on home page . I am testing it locall so home page is on localhost:8000

The error i am getting is commonly met : **"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `IndexPage`."**

````
import Routes, {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
      <>
          <BrowserRouter>
              <Header/>
              <Routes>
                  <CookieConsentModal/>
                  <Switch>
                      <Route path="/">
                          <Home/>
                      </Route>
                      <Route path="page/page1">
                          <DefyCryptoWallet/>
                      </Route>
                      <Route path="page/page2">
                          <SwapCrypto/>
                      </Route>
                  </Switch>
              </Routes>
              <Footer/>
          </BrowserRouter>
     </>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```
`




```
export default function Home() {

    return (
        <>
            <Layout>
                <Hero title='Welcome'/>
                <Article/>
            </Layout>

        </>
    )
}
```


```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
    return (
       <>
        <div className="wrap">
                <main className="articles">
                    { children }
                </main>
        </div>
       </>
    )
}
```
````

Comment: share Hero and Article components too

Comment: Which version of react router are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using V5 and V6 things from React Router. So which one are you using? `<Routes>` is a V6 thing, `<Switch>` is a V5 thing. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jd1umr?file=src/App.js) is a simple V5 router example. And [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ky53b4?file=src/App.js) is a simple V6 example.

> import Routes, {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

Change this import to match their documentation. They don't ever use the comma separated imports. `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';` is how it should be written for V5

Comment: Thank you @David, changed my code to use v6 and now it it working properly. Only one issue left.The issue comes when the url is for example "localhost:8000/page1" and i reload the page manually or type it in the browser. It loads the content but the Navigation is missing and the meta data (script , css) is not applied. What am i missing here . 
    `<MetaDecorator/>
      <CookieConsentModal/>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Navigation/>
              <Routes ><Route path="/page1" element={ <Page1/> }/></Routes>
          <Footer/>
      </BrowserRouter>`